# How to obtain value from vars

Tags: web2py, request.querystring

Am trying to get value from request.vars but end up getting a null value.
My code:

```
if request.vars.message:
    return request.vars.message
R = request.vars.message
return dict (R=R, form =form)
```

My vew.html
{{=R}}

This prints none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, whenever `request.vars.message` has a value, it immediately returns the value (inside the `if` block). The only case in which the code reaches the `return dict(...)` line at the end is when `request.vars.message` is missing (technically, any falsey value, but in most cases it is probably `None`, meaning there is no `message` key in the `request.vars` object).

If you want to send the value of `message` to the view to be displayed, then do not return inside the `if` block.